# Reading Custom Properties of File - Windows

Tags: python, file, python-3.4

My family has a hard time deciding what to eat for any particular week. Because of this, I am going to make a program that will select randomly select recipe files from a directory based on recipe attributes: amount of preparation required, serving temperature of the dish, etc.

In order to accomplish this, I am hoping to store recipe attributes in the custom attributes section of the file. Any suggestions on python modules that would allow me to access the custom properties? I am currently running Windows 10, if that makes any difference.

**Disclaimer:** I am aware that this question has been asked before. However, it has been quite a while, and the win32 solution suggested is not compatible with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Pywin32 has builds for Python3.4 available, both 32-bit and 64-bit.

But if you *know* which MS-Windows API calls you need, and you know which DLL they are in, you could always use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

---

Alternative solutions are to put the attributes in a file (probably in the root of your tree of recipes). Each method has its pros and cons.

- JSON (easiest to edit)
- A pickled `list` of `dict` or `namedtuple` object (fast to load, easy to use in your program)
- SQLite database (easiest to *select* recipes)

Since you want to choose from recipies based on criteria, the SQLite database might be the most suitable option in this case.